# apache - https is only working for site1, but site2 is not working in the same server

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, centos

CentOS: 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64:

I have 2 website in the same server now i have SSL certificate for site1.com and site2.com. site1.com is only working but site2.com is not working cause its showing site1.com

Example: when i visit

https://www.site1.com works perfectly
but when i visit: https://www.site2.com , then it does not show site2.com but showing site1.com like the Virtualhost is failing

Any advise what am i doing wrong here?

```
$ cat ssl.conf
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

# Site One
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site1/public"
  ServerName www.site1.com:443
   <Directory /var/www/html/site1/public>
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
  LogLevel warn
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/crt1.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/key1.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ca-bundle/root1.crt
  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
           nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
           downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost> 


# Site Two
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site2/public"
  ServerName www.site2.com:443
   <Directory /var/www/html/site2/public>
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
  LogLevel warn
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/crt2.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/key2.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ca-bundle/root2.crt
  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
           nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
           downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be missing `NameVirtualHost *:443` in your main config file. You can check whether the virtual host configurations are being picked up by examining the output of `apachectl -S`

Comment: Possible. Otherwise provide the dedicated IPs you have used for the SSL in the place of _*_